# Key events outside of an SDL application

Tags: c++, sdl, linux, gamepad

I'm developing an app under C++ and SDL running in Ubuntu. I'm using the SDL events to handle the keypad buttons. My problem is that my app launch other programs and it should close they with a key combination, but I can't detect the user presing buttons outside of my app.

¿How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XGrabKey](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgrabkey) if you're using an x environment (you probably are, unless you know otherwise)